# What is the default initialisation of array in ballerina?

Tags: arrays, initialization, ballerina

If I declare an array as below,

```
int[5] items = [];
```

What is the value the elements are initialised to?
When I print the int array elements, all elements are zero.

```
foreach int item in allocatedCubicles {
    io:println(item);
}
```

What about arrays initialised with other data types (float, string)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this part from the Ballerina spec https://ballerina.io/spec/lang/master/#FillMember

Most used types copied from the spec:

```
Type                             Filled value
-----------------------------------------------
boolean                              false  
int                                  0  
float                                +0.0f  
decimal                              +0d    
string                               ""     
array or tuple type descriptor       []
```

Example:

```
import ballerina/io;

public function main() {
    int[5] five = [];
    io:println(five); // [0,0,0,0,0]

    boolean[2] b2 = [];
    io:println(b2); // [false,false]

    int[] items = [];
    io:println(items); // []

    // now lets add some element at a specific index
    items[4] = 2;
    // Items 0, 1, 2, 3 are filled so that we can insert at index 4
    io:println(items); // [0,0,0,0,2]
}
```

Comment: I had a bounded array, when trying to print it. It may have caused some confusion. Updated the question to be more clear

Comment: Aha got it, update the answer a bit